# Pandas is not finding a missing value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The dataset:  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

```
missing_values = ["n/a", "na", "--","-"," -","-","?",' ?']
base = pd.read_csv("census.csv", na_filter=missing_values)
```

base has a ' ?' (exactly as I wrote) in `base["workclass"][27]`. I tried to mark it as missing value using the code below, but :

```
base["workclass"].isna().sum()
```

returns 0.

Why Pandas did not marked ' ?' as Nan?

Comment: How about: `base['workclass'].replace(to_replace=missing_values,value=np.nan)` ?

Comment: @Junkrat Should not Pandas  mark missing_values as Nan automatically? I opened csv using the filter...

Comment: Could you share a part of your data  so that your code can be checked and see what doesn't work

Comment: @ Junkrat   dataset -> https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult